# Is it possible for my app's content and theme to change depending on a scanned QR code by the user?

Tags: ios, database, integration, qr-code

Essentially, I have an integrated QR scanner in my app and my goal is to have it so the user must scan a QR code during the 'Sign Up' phase. The app idea is an extremely dynamic one in which its content and theme can change depending on the Sign Up phase. My idea was to have a QR code generated so that when the user scans that QR code, it tells the app:

"Okay, the user has scanned this particular QR code, his app should look like this, and should contain this".

Think of it as the QR code almost has its own license attached to it so the app knows the user belongs to a particular group.

I hope this makes sense and I need a Yes or No as to whether this is possible or not.

To summarise, the user scans a QR code during their Sign Up phase. The app realises that the user has scanned a particular QR code, and such the app's content and theme should change accordingly.

What sort of data should the QR code contain? And how would this app read this and make changes accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am in urgent need of a Yes or No as to whether this is possible or
>   not.

Yes this is possible.

> What sort of data should the QR code contain?

Anything you want as long as you associate it to a theme and content. You can find more information on QR codes [here](http://www.createqrcodes.org/how-do-qr-codes-work.html).

> how would this app read this

You can find that [here](https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=qr%20code%20reader%20swift) with a simple google search.

> make changes accordingly?

There are a lot of different ways you could do this. If this is happening on sign up then just keep a global variable or `NSUserDefaults` variable of their group and present information in the future accordingly.

Comment: thanks man, looking back it does seem rather simple indeed.

Comment: @HairySeal no problem and best of luck!